# I'm using Biblatex and some entries of my bibliogaphy are not printed

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing my thesis and I don't know why today I have reenabled the option to print the bibliography but now it doesn't work well.

Only some of the cited articles are shown.

My commands lines are:

```
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\lualatex.exe -synctex=1 
    -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
"C:/texlive/2019/bin/win32/biber.exe" %
```

`.tex` document:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside, spanish]{book}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[skip=12pt, indent=2em]{parskip}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, pdfencoding=auto,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}  
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\cref\autoref} 
\usepackage[style=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=3,style=numeric,backend=biber, 
       url=false,doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex} 
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}    \clearfield{urlmonth} }
\addbibresource{missings.bib}


\begin{document}

\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}
Some words \parencite{Barnard1999, STERNER2009}
redes de conexión \parencite{barabasi_network_2004}, 
More words \parencite{Wasserman1994, Ahuja1993}. 

Long text  \parencite{HosmerJr2013}. 

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,type=book,title={BIBLIOGRAFÍA}]

\end{document}
```

Everything else seems to work well, included the creation of bookmarks and crossreferences.

[image]

As you can see two references are missing.
What am I doing wrong?
I haven't modified the bib file in a long time and it seems to be OK.
I have tried removing the white spaces but the problem is still there.

I have extracted the biblatex code for these references by using Jabref:

```
@Book{Ahuja1993,
  author     = {Ahuja, Ravindra K. and Magnanti, Thomas L. and Orlin, James B.},
  title      = {Network flows: theory, algorithms, and applications},
  date       = {1993},
  file       = {Snapshot:Ahuja1993 - Network Flows_ Theory, Algorithms, and Applications.- 1993 - network flows theory, algorithms, and application:},
  groups     = {Sequences, All entries},
  shorttitle = {Network flows},
}

@Book{HosmerJr2013,
  author    = {Hosmer Jr, David W. and Lemeshow, Stanley and Sturdivant, Rodney X.},
  title     = {Applied Logistic Regression},
  date      = {2013},
  volume    = {398},
  publisher = {{John Wiley \& Sons}},
  groups    = {Other, All entries},
  timestamp = {2017-05-17T18:57:15Z},
}

@Book{Wasserman1994,
  author     = {Wasserman, Stanley and Faust, Katherine},
  title      = {Social network analysis: Methods and applications},
  date       = {1994},
  volume     = {8},
  publisher  = {Cambridge university press},
  file       = {Snapshot:Wasserman1994 - Social Network Analysis_ Methods and Applications.html:text/html},
  groups     = {Sequences, All entries},
  shorttitle = {Social network analysis},
}

@Article{Barnard1999,
  author          = {Barnard, J and Meng, X L},
  title           = {Applications of multiple imputation in medical studies: from AIDS to NHANES.},
  journal         = {Statistical methods in medical research},
  year            = {1999},
  volume          = {8},
  issue           = {1},
  month           = mar,
  pages           = {17--36},
  issn            = {0962-2802},
  doi             = {10.1177/096228029900800103},
  abstract        = {Rubin's multiple imputation ....},
  citation-subset = {IM, X},
  completed       = {1999-08-06},
  country         = {England},
  groups          = {Missing Data, All entries},
  issn-linking    = {0962-2802},
  keywords        = {Acquired Immunodeficiency Syndrome, mortality; Data Interpretation, Statistical; Epidemiologic Methods; Health Surveys; Humans; Models, Statistical; Monte Carlo Method; Population Surveillance, methods; Random Allocation; Research Design, statistics & numerical data; Survival Analysis},
  nlm-id          = {9212457},
  owner           = {NLM},
  pmid            = {10347858},
  pubmodel        = {Print},
  pubstatus       = {ppublish},
  references      = {44},
  revised         = {2017-02-14},
}


@Article{STERNER2009,
  author       = {STERNER, Jonathan AC and WHITE, Ian R. and CARLIN, John B. and SPRATT, Michael and ROYSTON, Patrick and KENWARD, Michael G. and WOOD, Angela M. and CARPENTER, James R.},
  title        = {Multiple Imputation for Missing Data in Epidemiological and Clinical Research: Potential and Pitfalls},
  journaltitle = {BMJ. British medical journal},
  date         = {2009},
  volume       = {339},
  number       = {7713},
  pages        = {157--160},
  url          = {http://cat.inist.fr/?aModele=afficheN&cpsidt=21677911},
  file         = {Snapshot:STERNER2009 - Multiple Imputation for Missing Data in Epidemiological and Clinical Research_ Potential and Pitfalls.html:text/html},
  groups       = {Missing Data, All entries},
  shorttitle   = {Multiple Imputation for Missing Data in Epidemiological and Clinical Research},
  timestamp    = {2017-05-17T17:59:26Z},
}


@Article{barabasi_network_2004,
  author       = {Barabasi, Albert-Laszlo and Oltvai, Zoltan N},
  title        = {Network biology: understanding the cell's functional organization},
  journaltitle = {Nature reviews genetics},
  date         = {2004},
  volume       = {5},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {101--113},
  file         = {:barabasi_network_2004 - Network Biology_ Understanding the Cell's Functional Organization.pdf:PDF},
  groups       = {Sequences, All entries},
}
```

If I use the "check integrity" option in jabref I get this message:
[image]
but I think there is nothing serious there.

If I add a `\nocite{*}`

I get this error, I don't know if it's related:

```
0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (180 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (181 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (184 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (185 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (188 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (189 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (192 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (193 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (196 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (197 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (200 0 R) out of range (0..5) ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (201 0 R) out of range (0..5) - filter-flate.c:55: premature end of data in flate filter ! pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (204 0 R) out of range (0..5) - pdfengine.cpp:1591: document has no pages ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream ! pdf-xref.c:478: cannot recognize version marker - pdf-xref.c:1364: trying to repair broken xref ! pdf-repair.c:326: cannot tell in file ! pdf-xref.c:1451: cannot open document ! pdf-xref.c:2325: cannot load document from stream
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `type=book` in your `\printbibliography` options. The references that are missing are articles. Use instead:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={BIBLIOGRAFÍA}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that option was used when my document class is a book.
I was also creating a new file just in case the older one had errors.

Comment: What about the pdf-xref.c:1634: object id (180 0 R) out of range (0..5) message?